Automatisn that makes Rust very complicated to learn
I'm trying to learn rust.
What makes it very hard for me to learn is, that there are a lot of automatisms, that do things "magically" under the hood.
For instance this example compiles and l1 and l2 have the same value:
fn main() {
    let mut s = "foo".to_string();
    let sr = &mut s;
    
    let l1 = sr.len();
    let l2 = (*sr).len();
}

It seems that the compiler does an "automatic dereference" when the dot operator is used.
I can understand that is Automatisms make things easier for experienced programmers but for beginners (who want to learn the basic concepts and who want to build a mental model of the language) they are a nighmare because they are hiding things and making things less explicit. I'm pretty sure, once I understood the basic concepts those magic Automatisms will be very helpful for me, but until then, they making learning harder.
Is there some way to turn this automatisms off (just for learning purposes) so that everything has to be written explicitely ?
Also reading other code is very hard with those "magic" sprinkled on top, because I never know what really happens under the hood and in the end I cannot comprehend the code. Are there some transpilers which can take "regular" rust code and transpile it to "explicit" rust code ?
thanks
Gerhard

Oh man, references stack up a lot, especially if you do some processing on iterators (e.g. map, filter, etc). Would it be more pleasant to write (******.sr).len() or |&&&&&sr| and then you add/remove reference in your function signature and have to add/remove an extra character all over your code? What really matters in Rust is whether something is owned String or borrowed: &String, &&String, &&&String it's all the same for me - it's not owned. I don't ever need to remember how many layers of references are out there, just the fact where it's owned

It would be annoying to have to write (&vec).len() or (&mut vec).push(123) if given a Vec<u32>. What you call automatism exists in all languages in some form, and is there for a reason. Don't worry about it too much in advance, and try to enjoy Rust for what it is!

No offense, but you do realize that your favorite managed language (C#?) does waaaaaay more magic than this under the hood for you?

Yes, you are all right. As I wrote I think those Automatism will be helpful for me too.
I just wanted to turn them off temporarily (with some switch) for the purpose of learning the concepts
E.g. like you learn in the school do do calculations by hand on a sheet of paper.
In the End you will be using calculators and computer anyways, but doing this things by hand, helped you to understand the concepts.

You may be interested in learning which dereferencing rules exist.

@ChayimFriedman did not DV mostly because I saw no need to pile on yet another one, but this does kinda read a bit... off? What's the OPs endgame here? Starting at assembler and moving up the tower of abstraction, what's the line of acceptable magic? What sorts of behavior (besides the mentioned automatic dereferencing) should this hypothetical toggle control? I don't think this question is well-formed enough to be answerable, even your answer (and tbc I'm a very big fan of your Rust answers) reads more like some practical learning/tooling advice than an answer to me.

While there is no way to turn it off, rust-analyzer can help you here (if you're using it).
Set the setting "rust-analyzer.inlayHints.expressionAdjustmentHints.enable": "reborrow" (or "always") and rust-analyzer will show where the compiler automatically borrows/dereferences.
If you are using RustRover, I don't know whether it has something equivalent.


Is there some way to turn this automatisms off (just for learning purposes) so that everything has to be written explicitely?

The simple answer to the question is: no, there is no way to turn off mechanisms like auto-dereferencing and deref coercion. That would make Rust much harder to use, and most of the existing code would not run.
